# ChannelBuffer decoding from hex send from terminal

Tags: java, encoding, hex, netty

I'm trying to decode packages sent by external device. I was able to capture sent data and I'm trying to simulate device connection with terminal, like so:

```
echo -ne "\xab\x10\xac\x03\xac\x9a\xcd\x09\x01" | nc -v localhost 5187
```

Data sent by device is read by following code:

```
ChannelBuffer buf = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN, (String)msg, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

int header = buf.readUnsignedByte();
int flags = buf.readUnsignedByte();
int length = buf.readUnsignedShort();
int checksum = buf.readUnsignedShort();
int index = buf.readUnsignedShort();
int type = buf.readUnsignedByte();
```

I guess that it should be like this (with little endian):

```
header   = HEX: ab   = DEC: 171
flags    = HEX: 10   = DEC: 16
length   = HEX: ac03 = DEC: 940
checksum = HEX: ac9a = DEC: 39596
index    = HEX: cd09 = DEC: 2509
type     = HEX: 01   = DEC: 1
```

But I got following results:

```
header   = 63
flags    = 16
length   = 831
checksum = 16191
index    = 2367
type     = 1
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? I'm trying to understand why my expectations are incorrect (`header` looks like sign problem, but it doesn't explain other).